# How would you vent my basement bathroom fan?

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, fan, air-quality

I have a basement bathroom basically smack dab in the middle of the basement.  The joists run from front-to-back of house.  So going out either side is not an option.  Going out the front is not an option because I will hit a slab porch.  So my ways out are back or up.

Going up entails going 4 feet doing a 90 up and then out the attic.  Going out the back - there is already duct work in the joist run the fan is on.  It is an unfinished laundry/storage room and would be about 15 feet total.

So I guess my options are go under duct work (sticking below joist a couple inches but still 7 feet up) and out back, do a couple 90s to move to joist over (going under joist temporarily then back up) and out the back, or going 5 feet over then 90 through the main floor then out the attic.

The attic would be a long run - 5 feet, plus 10 feet to get to attic, plus 15 feet to get to soffit.  To the back of the house would be 15-20 feet total.

Also I have thought about buying one of those no vent out machines that slowly releases humidity to laundry area.  The basement/house is dry and could use moisture.  Anything is in play!

Comment: If going with something other than venting out the house - it needs to pass inspection.

Comment: My experience with a condensing dryer (for an upstairs laundry in a condo, no new holes allowed) was that it is much slower and used cold water, also).  Extra moisture in the basement is never a good idea.  It may seem a good idea in winter, but the other 3 seasons are asking for mildew at best, mold at worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started out 4 inch rigid, then switched to a bendable aluminum for 8 feet so I could slip under a joist and back up another, and then straight rigid all the way through.  I slipped it under close to the main stack so it is kind of hidden in the web of crap anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is your furnace in the basement?  Is it forced air?

If so, the main supply run probably goes UNDER the joists... Attach your bath fan run alongside it.

Comment: I will look at that.  It runs perpendicular to joists.  It would have to go out the side and would run about 20 feet total.  This would go straight out then down then follow the along supply then up a little to get out (which will have to use flex sine the joist by side is not much more than 4 inches from concrete if that makes sense.  I need to get to the basement and look at this.